# Get the end address of Linux kernel function on run-time

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls

I am trying to get the boundary for a kernel function (system calls for example). Now, if I understand correctly, I can get the start address of the interested function by reading `/proc/kallsyms` or `System.map` but I dont know how to get the end address of this function.

As you may know, `/proc/kallsyms` allow us to view the symbol table for Linux kernel so we can see the start address of all exported symbols. Can we use the start address of the next function to calculate the end address of the previous function? If we cannot do like this, could you suggest me another ways?

Comment: Why do you need to know the "end address" of a function?

Comment: I need to know it because I want to do "function inlining" on run-time. After that, I can build Control Flow Graph which includes basic blocks of the interested function and all of its callees.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, executables store only the start address of a function, as it is all that is required to call the function. You will have to infer the end address, rather than simply looking it up.

You could try to find the start address of the subsequent function, but that wouldn't always work either. Imagine the following:

```
void func_a() {
    // do something
}

static void helper_function() {
    // do something else
}

void func_b() {
    // ...
    helper_function();
    // ...
}
```

You could get the address of `func_a` and `func_b`, but `helper_function` would not show up, because nothing needs to link to it. If you tried to use `func_b` as the end of `func_a` (assuming that the order in the compiled code in equivalent to the order in the source code, which is not guaranteed), you would end up accidentally including code that you didn't need to include - and might not find code that you need to find when inlining other functions into `func_b`.

So, how do we find this information? Well, if you think about it - the information *does* exist - all of the paths within `func_a` will eventually terminate (in a loop, return statement, tail call, etc), probably before `helper_function` begins.

You would need to parse out the code of `func_a` and build up a map of all of the possible code paths within it. Of course, you would need to do this anyway to inline other functions into it - so it shouldn't be too much harder to simply not care about the end address of the function.

One final note: in this example, you would have trouble finding `helper_function` in order to know to inline it, because the symbol wouldn't show up in `kallsyms`. The solution here is that you can track the `call` instructions in individual functions to determine what hidden functions exist that you didn't know about otherwise.

TL;DR: You can only find the end address by parsing the compiled code. You have to parse this anyway, so just do it once.